# Conditional doesn't work in angular.forEach

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make a comparison between two iterated values in a forEach but it does not behave as it should. in all cases the condition is fulfilled despite being valid.
I have been looking for something about it for a while and nothing.
Can anybody help me?

```
 angular.forEach($scope.shifts, function(value, key){
                        if(value.shift_id == $scope.shift){
                            $scope.selectedShift = $scope.shift;
                        }else{
                            $scope.selectedShift = value.shift_id;
                        }                            
                     });
```

For reference:

`$scope.shifts =`

```
[{ "shift_id": "7", "shift_name": "JuanIlario" }, 
 { "shift_id": "31", "shift_name": "Ruperto" } ]
```

and `$scope.shift`= '7';

[View example code](http://plnkr.co/edit/cUAgZVBNt7l2rDQ1psvV?p=preview)

Comment: please add what is $scope.shifts and $scope.shift

Comment: ** $scope.shifts** = [{
            "shift_id": "7",
            "shift_name": "JuanIlario"
            },
            {
            "shift_id": "31",
            "shift_name": "Ruperto"
            }
        ]
**$scope.shift** = [{
            "shift_id": "7",
            "shift_name": "JuanIlario"
            },
            {
            "shift_id": "31",
            "shift_name": "Ruperto"
            }
        ]

_the two are the same_

Comment: What do you mean with `the condition is fulfilled`, do you mean the condition yields `true` so the `then` part executes? And what do you mean by `despite being valid`? did you mean `despite being false`?

Comment: *See exact example please*  [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/cUAgZVBNt7l2rDQ1psvV?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in that `$scope.shift` is an array but `value.shift_id` is a string. So the comparison with `==` doesn't do what you expect.

I imagine you want to know if there is an element in `$scope.shift` that has a `shift_id` equal to `value.shift_id`. If that's the case, you need to traverse the array `$scope.shift` comparing every element's `shift_id` against `value.shift_id`.

Also, note that in each iteration you are overwriting the value stored in `$scope.selectedShift` so the only iteration that matters is the last, I doubt that is what you want, but as it's not clear from the code what you want to be able to give you a better solution.

Comment: That's only part of the problem. Will always be set based on last item in array only

Comment: was updating the answer with exactly that.

Comment: If so, here you can see it running [link code example](http://plnkr.co/edit/cUAgZVBNt7l2rDQ1psvV?p=preview)